# How to access time index while playing audio?

Tags: sound

I'd like to access the current time (in seconds) while playing audio.

For example:

```
song = Import@"file.mp3";
id = Audio`AudioInformation[song, "AudioID"];
```

Then start it playing programatically:

```
Audio`Internals`Execute[Audio`Internals`GetAudioManager[id], "Play"];
```

As it plays, I'd like to know the time index where it is currently playing:

```
Dynamic[$songPlayingProgress]
(*would update continuously, e.g.return 34.23 seconds....*)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
id = Audio`AudioInformation[song, "AudioID"];
mngr = Audio`Internals`GetAudioManager[id];
Dynamic@Audio`AudioDump`getGUIInfo[mngr, "AudioPosition"]
```

Comment: is there any shorter way